# Persist changes in multipass

Tags: server, virtualization, cloud, multipass

I'm using Canonical's Multipass version 1.4.0 on Windows 10, version 1909 (64-bit).

If I launch an Ubuntu instance and do some changes to it - say for instance, install some package using apt-get. How do I make the changes persist? That is, how do I make sure that the next time when I create an instance from this image, I wouldn't have to install that package again?

Answer (score 1):

The storage for virtual machines (VM) instances created with Multipass is persistent by default.  If you use "multipass launch --name primary source_image" to create a new instance, make modifications from a shell, shutdown, and then restart it later with "multipass start primary" or "multipass shell primary", then your changes will still be present.  "primary" is the default name for the instance if you don't specify, so could be omitted from above examples.   "multipass list" command shows the VM instances you have created.

If you want to create multiple instances that have the same modifications from the same base image, then I believe you could create a cloud-init customization script to modify each instance the same way.  cloud-init customiztoin method can be used to install packages on first run, create users, setup approved SSH keys, register locally generated unique keys, mount shared file systems, etc.

From https://ubuntu.com/blog/using-cloud-init-with-multipass
"[Cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/) is the standard for customizing cloud instances and now multipass can also make use of cloud-init to customize an instance during launch. "

The Multipass terminology is a little confusing (or at least was to me at first), but hopefully this helps to clarify.  The essential thing to understand is do NOT use "multipass **launch**" command again to bring back an existing instance to running state, because **the launch command is only used the first time to create a NEW VM instance.**   For more detail on commands, I found the most complete documentation is built-in using the "multipass help" command, which has more commands shown than the [online multipass command documentation](https://multipass.run/docs).

As I understand it, the biggest advantage of using Multipass is quickly creating new blank or cloud-init configured Ubuntu Server VMs on a local host machine, and then managing them at very high level (start,stop,delete,transfer files, etc.).  I have found that Multipass is not well suited for moving an Ubuntu server VM instance between hosts/hypervisors or copying a configured VM instance (hard to export the VM data).  If you only need one persistent Ubuntu VM (and maybe back it up or replicate), you might be better off just managing that guest VM using your native VM host management tool by creating a blank guest machine and [installing Ubuntu Server onto the guest VM](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/general) from [a downloaded Live ISO file for  Ubuntu server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server).   Good luck.

Comment: " If you use "multipass launch --name primary source_image" to create a new instance, make modifications from a shell, shutdown, and then restart it later with "multipass start primary" or "multipass shell primary", then your changes will still be present." - What about the situation when I restart Windows itself? That's my key concern.

Comment: Yes. if you restart Windows, that will shutdown the virtual machine (VM) host environment (Hyper-V, VirtualBox, etc), which should result in same behavior as suspending any running guest VM instance by preserving the disk and even the memory state.  After the host (Windows) reboots, you probably need to activate the guest VM instance.  Use "multipass list" to show  which VM instances you have created and if they are running, and if needed, use "multipass start" or "multipass shell" to bring them back to life.